# I used JAXB to convert my XML into json. Now, how do i extract specific content from it?

Tags: java, json, xml, jaxb

Is there another way without having to use JSONObject?

My code:(What I have tried so far)

```java
@Path("rdescriptions")
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public RSet getRDescriptions() throws JAXBException {
    File file = new File("../RSet.xml");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(RSet.class);
    Unmarshaller um = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    RSet rs = (RSet) um.unmarshal(file);
    return rs;
}
```

JSON that gets generated:

```
 "Rule":[{"ID":"t1","desc":"Something","order":1,"result":{"com":0,"no":
 {"word":[{}]}},"we":{"T":[{"set":0,"IS":{"v":{"EF":[{}]}}}]}},   
 {"ID":"t2","desc":"Html","order":1...]
```

I want to extract only the ID for each. Can someone please explain how to go about doing this?

Comment: Where is the code for `RSet`? What is your desired output?